# Variadic generic type for python's TypedDict?

Tags: python, python-typing

I'd like to do something like:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, TypedDict

 T = TypeVar("T")

class Foo(Generic[T], TypedDict):
    bar: T
    ...

foo: Foo[int] = {"bar": 42}
```

But this yields a type error ("cannot inherit from both a TypedDict and a non-TypedDict base class").

Are there any ways to achieve this result?

Comment: Seems like this is not possible at the moment, see [this issue for more details](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89026)

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM: Post that as an answer?

Answer (score 15):

This is not possible at the moment. You [cannot inherit from both a TypedDict and a non-TypedDict base class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/typing.py#L2346). But there is [issue active on the cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89026) repository and a [discussion](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89026#issuecomment-1093924869) going on to support this feature.

EDIT: As per the [latest update](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89026#issuecomment-1116093221), this feature is now available in [python 3.11](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89026).

Comment: Do you know any workaround for Python 3.10?

Answer (score 1):

If one can't upgrade to Python 3.11, a workaround would be to use [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) module instead of built-in typings module. I use Python 3.10 and typing-extensions 4.9.0 and it works as expected.